# ASP.NET Core web application returns different response headers for every request

Tags: http, asp.net-core, http-headers, content-length, transfer-encoding

Response Transfer-Encoding header's value is not always present.
There is an ASP.NET Core(Razor) web app hosted on localhost. A small console application periodically(every 2-3 minutes) makes 45 HttpWebRequest to the web app for different resources(home page, other web pages, static images, js, CSS). Every time the console app compares the old page/image/css content and response headers, for the majority of resources there are no changes but for some of them, the response headers are different in 90% of cases.

```
response nr 1 headers:
"Content-Length" : "12714"
"Content-Type" : "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

```
response nr 2 headers:
"Content-Type" : "text/html; charset=utf-8"
"Transfer-Encoding" : "chunked"
```

```
response nr 3 headers:
"Content-Length" : "12714"
"Content-Type" : "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

Why does the ASP.NET Core response headers are almost always different?
ASP.NET web app is hosted on IIS Express.
One time the response is chunked and in this case, the  **Content-Length** header is omitted, but why one time the response is chunked and another time not?

Comment: Take a look at [Chunked Encoding](https://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/chunked/#:~:text=Chunked%20encoding%20is%20useful%20when,results%20from%20a%20database%20query.), I think it depends on what you do on the server side。

Comment: Resources(page/js/image/css) are not changed at all, checked and have found that this issue does not reproduce on production where there are Kestrel server